# Webpack 5 sass-loader not compiling nested scss files

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

I am setting up Webpack for my first time and I am getting stuck on the Sass part.

I have a file structure like this:

- src (dir)

  - styles (dir)

    - utilities (dir)

      - test.scss
  - index.scss (this is in the root of src)
  - index.js (this is in the root of src)

`test.scss` has this in it:

```
$blue: dodgerblue;

body {
  background-color: $blue;
}
```

`index.scss` has this:

```
@import url("./styles/utilities/test.scss");
```

my entry file is `index.js` and below if I use the import in #1 it works, the scss compiles correctly, but if I use the import in #2 it does not compile.

1. `import './styles/utilities/test.scss';`
2. `import './index.scss';`

The output for #1 looks like this:

```
body {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

The output for #2 looks like this:

```
body {
  background-color: $blue;
}
```

Why is this happening? Ultimately, I would like to be able to organize my stylesheets in different folders and be able to compile all of them into css.

my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {autoprefixer: {}}
              }
            }
          },
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "index.css"
  })],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.scss']
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured it out. We should be using [Sass Modules](https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched) instead of `@import`. Also, this video helped me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0

When I replaced `@import` with `@use` it started working.

Answer (score 0):

this is my configs object for scss, and it's working with `import`.
You would need to install `autoprefixer` and add a `css-loader` and a `style-loader` loaders

```
 {
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            use: [{
              // inject CSS to page
              loader: 'style-loader'
            }, {
              // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
              loader: 'css-loader'
            }, {
              // Run postcss actions
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                // `postcssOptions` is needed for postcss 8.x;
                // if you use postcss 7.x skip the key
                postcssOptions: {
                  // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                  plugins: function () {
                    return [
                      require('autoprefixer')
                    ];
                  }
                }
              }
            }, {
              // compiles Sass to CSS
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }]

    },
```